# Show one picture on tablet and different picture on pc

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this problem...I am running page http://exploreprague.cz. In the right upper corner I have ribbon. But when I am looking on it on my tablet, its's overlapping my menu. So I figured that if there is way to show different picture(different kind of ribbon, not just differently styled) it could work. But I don't know if there is some kind of HTML/CSS/JS trick which can do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the better ways to achieve what you want would be to use [**CSS3 Media queries**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

In the CSS file targeted at tablet-sized resolutions, you could set `display:none` on that particular image, and replace it with a new image that fits in with your smaller resolution better if you prefer.

**For example** (iPad portrait/landscape resolution):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  #oldImg { display:none; }
  #newImg { display:block; }
}
```

Comment: This worked good, I have to only add the pc screen resolution interval. Thx

Comment: Although, this means that both images would be loaded whether you were on a tablet or desktop, which could slow performance.

Comment: @Alfo True, but looking at the question and it's tags, it's hard to think of a solution that wouldn't involve uploading both images. Also, considering in the user's case it's only one image, it shouldn't affect performance noticeably, if it were many images however, it might be a different story..

Comment: Obviously you'd have to upload both images but what you should probably do is use CSS3 media queries to only apply the background styles when they matched the device.

Comment: @Alfo That is basically what I meant, but yeah I could have not included the #oldimg at all in the iPad CSS and it'll work fine too

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use a responsive css:

```
        Large desktop 
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            #largeImage{
                 display: inline;
            }
            #smallImage{
                 display: none;
            }
        }

        Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop 
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
            #largeImage{
                 display: none;
            }
            #smallImage{
                 display: inline;
            }
        }

        Landscape phone to portrait tablet 
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            /* do the same as tablets or include this width range in the tablet style*/
        }

        Landscape phones and down 
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            /* do the same as tablets or include this width range in the tablet style*/}
```

Just set the image display property according to the width of the screen.
use 2 images one with

```
display: none;
```

and the other with:

```
display: inline;
```

and switch between them on a narrower screen

Comment: At the beginning the second answer did not contain an example so I figure it would be more informative to add it.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try both ways when I am at my computer and I will tell you which solution was better suited for my problem.

Comment: So I finally tried, but when I looked at it now, on my computer screen it won't show and on my tablet I can see two overlapping pictures now. My tablet is iPad and my computer screen resolution is 1366x768